# Please make sure the libxml2 and libxslt development packages are installed

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I need to docker-compose django project in which i used 'facebook_scraper' package. Im trying to compose up following docker file:

```
###########
# BUILDER #
###########
# pull official base image
FROM python:3.8.3-alpine as builder
# set work directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
# install psycopg2 dependencies
RUN apk update \
    && apk add postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev
RUN apk add --update --no-cache --virtual .build-deps g++ libxml2-dev libxslt-dev && \
    apk add --no-cache libxslt && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir lxml>=3.5.0 && \
    apk del .build-deps
# lint
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install flake8
COPY . .
RUN flake8 --ignore=E501,F401 .
# install dependencies
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip wheel --no-cache-dir --no-deps --wheel-dir /usr/src/app/wheels -r requirements.txt
#########
# FINAL #
#########
# pull official base image
FROM python:3.8.3-alpine
# create directory for the app user
RUN mkdir -p /home/app
# create the app user
RUN addgroup -S app && adduser -S app -G app
# create the appropriate directories
ENV HOME=/home/app
ENV APP_HOME=/home/app/web
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
# install dependencies
RUN apk update && apk add libpq
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/wheels /wheels
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache /wheels/*
# copy entrypoint-prod.sh
COPY ./entrypoint.prod.sh $APP_HOME
# copy project
COPY . $APP_HOME
# chown all the files to the app user
RUN chown -R app:app $APP_HOME
# change to the app user
USER app
# run entrypoint.prod.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/home/app/web/entrypoint.prod.sh"]
```

but got error:

```
#0 69.33     Error: Please make sure the libxml2 and libxslt development packages are installed.
```

I installed followed package in docker file:

```
RUN apk add --update --no-cache --virtual .build-deps g++ libxml2-dev libxslt-dev && \
    apk add --no-cache libxslt && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir lxml>=3.5.0 && \
    apk del .build-deps
```

but it didnt worked.
I added lxml==4.9.2 in requirements.txt, but got new error:

```
ERROR: lxml-4.9.2-cp38-cp38-musllinux_1_1_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

After this i tried to change the python:3.8.3-alpine to python:3.8.3-slim and got new problem.
Im new at docker+django and dont know how to do. Can you explain me what i did wrong and show the way to solve the problem?

Comment: What hardware are you running this on?

Comment: im using macos.

Comment: Are you using an M1 or M2 Mac?  If so, you have an x86 wheel, when you need an amd64 wheel.